# Comparing two unequal length Data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I've two data frames which are pretty large.

```
mega_df.head()

L_Day             back_hr    Lat        Lon     AGL  Pressure   BT_time
1998-01-01 11:00:00   0     75.197  -150.045    1000    900.8   1998-01-01 11:15:00
1998-01-01 11:00:00 -0.2    75.245  -150.001    1002.4  900.5   1998-01-01 11:00:00
1998-01-01 11:00:00 -1.2    75.447  -149.863    1011.2  899.2   1998-01-01 10:00:00
1998-01-01 11:00:00 -2.2    75.661  -149.785    1019.3  898.3   1998-01-01 09:00:00
1998-01-01 11:00:00 -3.2    75.887  -149.762    1028.1  897.1   1998-01-01 08:00:00
1998-01-01 11:00:00 -4.2    76.124  -149.778    1038.3  895.9   1998-01-01 07:00:00
1998-01-01 11:00:00 -5.2    76.368  -149.818    1051.1  894.3   1998-01-01 06:00:00
1998-01-01 11:00:00 -6.2    76.607  -149.882    1065.2  892.5   1998-01-01 05:00:00
1998-01-01 11:00:00 -7.2    76.832  -149.969    1078    890.9   1998-01-01 04:00:00

df.head()

    ID            Lat   Lon   Elevation State   Name         FirstYr    LastYr  NObs
0   ACM0007886  17.117  -61.783 10.0    NaN COOLIDGE FIELD (UA) 1947    1993    13896
1   AEM0004121  24.433  54.650  16.0    NaN ABU DHABI INTERNA   1983    2017    35306
2   AEXUAE0546  25.250  55.370  4.0     NaN SHARJAH             1935    1942    2477
3   AFM0004091  36.700  67.200  378.0   NaN MAZAR-I-SHARIF      2010    2014    2179
4   AFM0004091  36.666  68.916  433.0   NaN KUNDUZ              2010    2013    4540
```

What I want is to get unique L_Day for which the Lat, Lon points in mega_df comes close to the values in df. For Eg; unique L_Day values for which (Lat in mega_df - Lat in df) < Value AND (Lon in mega_df - Lon in df) < Value. I want this "Value" to be flexible. So far I came up with this:

```
for la, lo in zip(list(df.lat), list(df.lon)):
    print(mega_df.index[((mega_df.Lat - la) < 0.005) &((mega_df.Lon - lo) < 0.005)].unique())
```

My first question is that is there any faster (panda-in built function) to do this? I can't use pd.isin() as I'm not looking for an exact match. And the syntax of pd.subtract() says that I've to subtract with an equivalent series.

Secondly, I would like to get the station names from df for which the above condition is satisfying. What I could come with is:

```
for la, lo in zip(list(df.lat), list(df.lon)):
    for mla,mlo in zip(list(mega_df.Lat), list(mega_df.Lon)):
        if (((mla - la) < 0.05) & ((mlo - lo) < 0.05)):
            print(df4.Name[(df4['Lat'] == la) & (df4['Lon'] == lo)].unique())
```

This looks very inefficient as both of my data frames are huge and isn't even giving me any output in jupyter notebook after waiting for 30+ mins. How can I do this in an efficient way?

```
len(mega_df)
>>214170
len(df)
>>2761
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a complete solution but `zip(list(df.lat), list(df.lon))` is going to unecessarily create two giant lists. Try looping over `df` using `for row in df.itertuples():`

Comment: I finished testing zip method with df.itertuples() and zip seems to be much faster for the small data I tested with. Also, will df.itertuples not create 2 giant tuples? Moreover, the zip() is creating a list only for one column whereas df.itertuples() would create tuple object for all the columns in the df. Or I'm misunderstanding it and the later is not creating a new tuple object but somehow pointed to the same df?

Comment: `df.itertuples()` does not create tuples for the columns. It creates a tuple for each row (Namedtuple actually). But being a generator it only creates the tuple when you ask for it so it scales with large data. You can still drop the `list` and just do `zip(df.lat, df.lon)` to avoid creating the interim list.

Comment: How would I know if a function is a generator in the context of Pandas? The documentation of this function doesn't mention that but in df.iterows(), says it's a generator. So is it safe to assume that the Pandas functions with "it" are generators?

Comment: You can always just execute `df.itertuples()` on the python command line and see what it outputs. This case it outputs a `map` not a `generator` (I was wrong) but the map will behave in a similar fashion where it will not cause memory problems. I don't know why the pandas documentation wasn't explicit about that.